# ccx - calculix: why occurs an error when I want to execute ccx?

Tags: linux, fortran, ubuntu-14.04, gfortran, abaqus

I've installed ccx (Calculix solver programm) to solve a physical problem. The preprocessor cgx works fine, but when I run ccx with an .inp file (abaqus) in terminal, there comes an error:

```
ccx: symbol lookup error: ccx: undefined symbol: _gfortran_internal_malloc
```

when I only run ccx without a flag or .inp file, the result is:

```
Usage: CalculiX.exe -i jobname
```

I have libgfortran3 installed on my ubuntu 14.04 computer (64 bit: x86_64) and link the "libgfortran.so.3.0.0" file in "/usr/lib/x86_64/" with a created reference object file "libgfortran.so.2" (calculix needs that file 'cause the application runs on 32 bit). Without that reference file ccx doesn't work completely and thats why I had to link it. I use Calculix 2.8p2.

Comment: You cannot link a 64bit library into a 32bit library location and expect 32bit libraries to use it correctly. You need to install the 32bit version of the library.

Comment: you mean that I have to link the libgfortran.so.3.0.0 in i386-linux-gnu directory with libgfortran.so.2 reference?

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually link **anything** anywhere. Doing that (in a system directory) is basically **always** wrong. You need to install the correct version of the correct architecture of the library you need for your tool to run. Ubuntu should have a 32bit version available for install alongside the 64bit version I would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is 32 bit, it needs 32 bit libraries to work.  What you've done is install 64 bit libraries and then symlinked them to where the 32 bit library should be.  This satisfies that the library "exists" but it will be unusable for the 32 bit program.

My library locations will differ from yours, but observe that they are different:

- 64 bit libgfortran.so

  ```
  $ file /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.2.0/libgfortran.so.3.0.0 
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.2.0/libgfortran.so.3.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
  ```
- 32 bit libgfortran.so

  ```
  $ file /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.2.0/32/libgfortran.so.3.0.0 
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.2.0/32/libgfortran.so.3.0.0: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
  ```

Secondly, if your program needs `libgfortran.so.2`, then symlinking a version of `libfortran.so.3` in its place will not work.  The change in library version number is a good signal that they are not compatible and not interchangeable.  You will need to find a package that provides the older library for i386 architecture.  This might mean installing a package from an older version of ubuntu.

Comment: that was what I've already done but forget to say, I've installed libfortran3 i386, but the error occours nevertheless :/ as I had mentioned ccx needs libfortran2 and not 3

Comment: @mistgabel then you'll need to find a package that provides libgfortran2 which means a gcc 4.2 era set of packages. search for some and try installing.

Comment: ok...thank you. I'll try this later, now I'm not at home. Tomorrow I'm going to write the result.

Comment: yes, I could try this and installed the <b>right</b> lib's from source, so that I've made some changes in paths in the makefiles. Now it works. My mistake was to install it from binary, that means with pre-configs that don't works on my system.